# test endpoints of a website using msal for authentication

Tags: python, testing, azure-ad-msal

Hi I have an app that uses Flask and msal for authentication on every page (you're redirected to azure for authentication if you're not logged in already, and then redirected to the page you requested)

How can i set up the tests in python to test the endpoints? And how can i do that on a CI machine that doesn't have a microsoft account? is it possible to mock a token somehow?